# What is wrong with this query, multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, select, error-handling, insert

what is wrong with this MySQL query and how do i solve it?

```
SELECT f.uniqueidentifier FROM db.engine4_passport_userforms uf
INNER JOIN db.engine4_passport_forms f ON uf.form_id = f.form_id
WHERE uf.user_id = 10
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationchildren (parentid, `First Name`, Surname, Relationship) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, '', '', '')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationcontactdetails (Address, Telephone, UID, Postcode) VALUES ('3 street', '',  f.uniqueidentifier, 'aaaaaa')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationcontactprefs (parentid, prefs) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, 'Post Email ')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationfoundus (parentid, medium, `reason for joining`) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, '', '')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationhousehold (parentid, `chief earner occupation`, `number of people`, `number of children`) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, 'build', '1', '0')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationinterests (parentid, interest) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, '')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationpersonaldetails (parentid, ethnicity) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, 'White')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationqanda VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, '4', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '5', '5', '3', '4', '5', '4')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationteam (parentid, team?, `no of team members`, relationship) VALUES ( f.uniqueidentifier, 'No', '', '')
INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationuserlink (userid, regformUID) VALUES ('10',  f.uniqueidentifier);
```

Here is the error i am getting:

```
Script line: 1  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationchildren (parentid, `Fir' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are **multiple** queries and not just **one**. Add `;` in between to seperate them:

```
select ....
inner join ...
where ...;

insert into ...;
values ...

...
```

### edit

if you want to use a value from a previous select then you can use a variable. Example:

```
SELECT @var := f.uniqueidentifier 
FROM db.engine4_passport_userforms uf
INNER JOIN db.engine4_passport_forms f ON uf.form_id = f.form_id
WHERE uf.user_id = 10;

INSERT INTO db.engine4_passport_registrationchildren (parentid, `First Name`, Surname, Relationship) 
VALUES (@var, '', '', '');
```

Comment: if i do this it will say `unknown coloumn f.uniqueindentifier in field list`

Comment: Then there is no such column named `uniqueindentifier`in your table.

Comment: there is because if i run `SELECT f.uniqueidentifier FROM engine4_passport_userforms uf
INNER JOIN db.engine4_passport_forms f ON uf.form_id = f.form_id
WHERE user_id = 10;` it returns what i want

Comment: don't put a `;` between the `select` and the `inner join`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17615/discussion-between-ryan-murphy-and-juergen-d)

Answer (score 0):

multiple queries must be terminated by the simicolon `;`. Single query is okay without the semicolon but if you send multiple queries to mysql server they must be terminated by `;`

Comment: if i do this it will say `unknown coloumn f.uniqueindentifier in field list`